# edittext focus shifts to first row in listview in android after typing first letter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

I have 10 rows in the ListView with each row containing a EditText. The Listview rendered fine.But When I try to edit the EditText  in the 3 rd row the focus from 3rd row is shifted to the 1st row after typing the first digit.

For example : when I try to type "39" in the 3rd row, after typing the digit "3" the 1st row's EditText gains focus and the next digit "9" is
printed in first row.

Source code

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/classmenulistview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
    android:dividerHeight="4px"
     />
```

I tried beforeDescendants. Even that is not working.

and the EditText in row_layout code :

```
          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/awardsedit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:digits=".1234567890"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" > 
             </EditText>
```

I make this EdiText visible from adatper.

IN Manifest file :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ClassName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_award_marks" >
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please help me

Comment: kindly debug your app...and then provide additional information

Comment: First off, there is lot of issues having edit text in listview. If there are only few items, try using scrollview instead of creating a listview. Try changing descendantFousability to "beforeDescendants".

Comment: I tried with "beforeDescendants". That too did not work..My items are not fixed count. They are dynamic. Can you please suggest me the alternative approach?